# Uploading file through html form and sending it as an attachment with email in mulesoft

Tags: mule

I'm using a html form to choose a file to be attcahed as an attachment in an email.

HTML form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <head></head>
<body>

Email Address: <input type="text" name="address" id="address"  
placeholder="Recipient's email add"/>
<label for='message' >Write Your Message *:</label><br/>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='message' id='message'></textarea>
Enter your Name  : <input type="text" name="name" id="name" 
placeholder="Sender's Name"/>
Sending Email To: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"
placeholder="Recipient's Name"/>
Upload your file :<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
<input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" id="reset"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>`
```

In attachment transformer I'm setting that file.

Xml is :

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" 
port="8083" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" >
</http:listener-config>   

<smtp:gmail-connector name="Gmail" contentType="text/html" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Gmail"/>

<flow name="parsetemplateforemailFlow">
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" 
doc:name="HTTP"   />
<parse-template location="*...file.html"/>
</flow>
<flow name="parsetemplateforemailFlow2">
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/login" 
doc:name="HTTP"/>
<logger message="#[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<set-attachment attachmentName="file.png" value="#[payload.file]" 
contentType="image/png" doc:name="Attachment"/>
<set-variable variableName="emailaddress" value="#[payload.address]"  
doc:name="Variable"/>

<set-variable variableName="senderName" value="#[payload.name]"
doc:name="Variable"/>
<set-variable variableName="recipient" value="#[payload.email]" 
doc:name="Variable"/>
<set-variable variableName="content" value="#[payload.message]" 
doc:name="Variable"/>
<component class="parsetemplateforemail.Email" doc:name="Java"/>
<logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" 
user="*************" password="**********" connector-ref="Gmail" to="
#[flowVars.emailaddress]" from="*********" subject="Test Email" 
responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

But I'm getting a blank file as an attachment. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have little modified your code and it is working for me.

HTML Code

```
<html> <head></head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="http://localhost:9091/send">
Email Address: <input type="text" name="address" id="address"    placeholder="Recipient's email add"/> <br/>
<label for='Body' >Write Your Message *:</label><br/><br/>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='body' id='body'></textarea><br/><br/>
Upload your file :<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/><br/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
<input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" id="reset"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Mule flow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:smtp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp/current/mule-smtp.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd">
<smtp:gmail-connector name="gmail" contentType="text/html" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Gmail"/>

<flow name="parsetemplateforemailFlow" doc:name="parsetemplateforemailFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9091" doc:name="HTTP" path="test"/>
    <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/html" doc:name="Property"/>
    <parse-template location="index.html" doc:name="Parse Template"/>
</flow>
<flow name="parsetemplateforemailFlow2" doc:name="parsetemplateforemailFlow2">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="9091" path="send" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-variable variableName="emailaddress" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.address]"  doc:name="Variable"/>
    <expression-filter expression="#[flowVars.emailaddress != &quot;&quot;]" doc:name="Expression"/>
    <logger message="Sending email to :: #[flowVars.emailaddress]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-attachment attachmentName="file.png" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.file]" contentType="image/png" doc:name="Attachment"/>
    <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.body]"/>
    <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587"   
                             to="#[flowVars.emailaddress]" 
                            from="Sadiq" subject="Test Email" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP" connector-ref="gmail" 
                            password="Katihar1981" user="sadique.arslan%40gmail.com"/>

    <logger message="Email sent." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow> 
</mule>
```